# ReactJS if this.props.myVar == ''something' not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have the following:

```
var chartOptions = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    callback: (v) => {
                        if (v < 3600000) {
                            return this.callFormat(v)
                        }
                    },
                    stepSize: (this.props.mode == 'calls' ? 7200 : 1000)
                }
            }]
        }
    };
```

However when `this.props.mode` **is** 'calls', it always returns false from within my object and so always results in 1000.

I have tried doing this a few different ways at it just seems like any if on `this.props` is completely ignored when the variable is what it should be.

Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

---

```
if (this.props.mode == 'calls') {
        var stepSize = 7200
    }
    var chartOptions = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    callback: (v) => {
                        if (v < 3600000) {
                            return this.callFormat(v)
                        }
                    },
                    stepSize
                }
            }]
        }
    };
```

Also does not work.

---

**Parent**

```
...
<div className="col-xs-6">
    {!this.state.chart_loading ? <Chart data={this.state.chart_data}
    mode={this.state.stat_view}/> : null}
</div>
...
```

**Chart.js**

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Line as LineChart} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import Numeral from 'numeral';

export default class Chart extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
    }

    callFormat(seconds) {
        var time = Numeral(seconds).format('00:00:00');
        var bits = time.split(':');
        var str = '';
        if (bits[0] > 0) {
            str += bits[0] + 'h';
        }
        if (bits[1] > 0) {
            if (bits[1] < 10 && bits[0] == 0) {
                str = bits[1].substr(1, 1) + 'm';
            } else {
                str += ' ' + bits[1] + 'm';
            }
        }
        if (bits[0] == 0 && bits[1] == 0) {
            str = 0;
        }
        return str;
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.mode == 'calls') {
            var stepSize = 7200
        }
        var chartOptions = {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        callback: (v) => {
                            if (v < 3600000) {
                                return this.callFormat(v)
                            }
                        },
                        stepSize
                    }
                }]
            }
        };



        return (
            <LineChart data={this.props.data} options={chartOptions} width={950} height={250}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: if you could give how to use this component , it will be great.

Comment: I've added more info.

Comment: can you show how you're passing the mode prop in / what's setting that prop?

Comment: It is coming from: {!this.state.chart_loading ? <Chart data={this.state.chart_data} mode={this.state.stat_view}/> : null} I have console logged in the render of Chart.js and it is how it should be, which is why i don't understand why logic isn't working.